# How can i get data or pass a data from one page to another after submitting a form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i am new to Reactjs, i'm almost done with my project. i've been doing a hotel booking system. but i have a problem with my checkout page. after i submitted a form from booking page it will redirected to checking out page. now how can i be able to get the reservation data from query? i'm using a param in my other pages but how can i pass an id when it was redirected and no href to pass the id.
can anyone help me with this, i'm runnung out of time and i'm still stuck here. thank you in advance.

here is my CheckOutPage:

```
   const CheckoutPage = (props) => {
   const [isRedirected, setIsRedirected] = useState(false)

if (isRedirected) {
    return <Redirect to='/transaction'/>
}

return (
    <ConfirmationMessage setIsRedirected={setIsRedirected}/>
)

}

const ConfirmationMessage = ({setIsRedirected}) => {

const { user } = useContext(UserContext)

const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [roomPrice, setRoomPrice] = useState(0)

let options = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.token
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    GQLClient(options).request(Query.getUser).then((data) => {
        setName(data.getUser.name)
    })

    GQLClient({}).request(Query.getRooms).then((data) => {

        setRoomPrice(data.getRoom.roomPrice)
    })

}, [])

return(
    <Container>
        <Row> .....
```

here's in my schema.js

```
 type Query {
    getReservationForm: ReservationForm
 }

 type ReservationForm {
    id: ID!
    startDate: String!
    endDate: String!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    contactDetail: String!
    roomNumber: String!
    roomPrice: Float!
}
```

in my resolvers

```
 Query: {
    getReservationForm: (parent, args) => {
        return ReservationForm.findById(args.id)
    }
},
```

and in my query

```
 getReservationForm: `
    query (
        $id: String!
    ) {
        getReservationForm (
            id: $id
        ) {
            startDate
            endDate
            name
            email
            contactDetail
            roomNumber
            roomPrice
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Redirect, you can actually pass some data:

```
<Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/checkout',
            state: { first: 'James', last: 'Bond', ... }
        }}
/>
```

You can then access this data in your CheckoutPage:

```
console.log(this.props.location.state);
```

Comment: if i want to pass the id. can i make it like these: state: { id: item.id  }

Comment: Yes, you can pass anything you want inside an object named `state`

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object

Comment: thank you very much, also the link is a big help! i'll mark this as solve